# Scheduled delivery of messages in IBM MQ - how far ahead in time?

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Scheduled Delivery of messages allows the calling application to specify a delivery delay when sending a message. The queue manager does not deliver the message until after the specified delivery delay has elapsed.

**Question**

Just to understand the viable operating parameters, how far ahead in time can we schedule the delayed delivery and expect the system to perform reliably ? E.g 1-2 days, weeks, months?

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the API signature does not impose any upper limit.

However, the intent of this question is about understanding the practical boundaries of a system beyond which it has not been tested or not guaranteed to perform reliably.

**IBM documentation**

I could not find anything specific in IBM's documentation in this context.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm

**AWS Simple Queue Services**

To set the context, AWS SQS supports a maximum delay of 15 minutes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html

**UPDATE**

Added link to AWS SQS docs.

Thanks

Comment: This post describes it: https://listserv.meduniwien.ac.at/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind2001&L=mqser-l&F=&S=&P=4504

Comment: So what the max in ms since jan 1st 1970 you can fit in a Java long is how far ahead you can go.   I read this is 17 Aug 292278994 07:12:55 GMT, more than 292 million years in the future.

Comment: if it works for minutes, why shouldn't it work for days/months/years ? The parameter i sof type long in milliseconds, so that should have you covered.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  The intent of this question is about understanding the practical boundaries of a system beyond which it has not been tested or not guaranteed to perform reliably.  I am not picking holes of finding faults in the system.  To be more specific, would you recommend scheduling a message with a 6 month delay?

Comment: As the documentation you linked to states, messages sent with a delayed delivery are simply placed in a staging queue `SYSTEM.DDELAY.LOCAL.QUEUE`.  It also states "The system queue must be altered so that its MAXMSGL and MAXDEPTH attributes are sufficient for the expected load."

Comment: If your MQ infrastructure exists in 10 years and you have the space to hold messages, the why couldn't you add a delay of that long?  I support systems that we have maintained continuously for over 10 years, they have of course moved from server to server, OS to OS, MQ version to MQ version, but we do this in a way that no outstanding messages are lost.  Obviously putting something with a delay of 200 million years from now may be a issue, so some realistic judgement should be used based on how long you expect the queue manager to be around.

Comment: @JoshMc  Thanks for responding. As per your experience in the environments that you have worked in - what was the longest delay that you have seen being applied ?

Comment: This is a newer feature,  one we are not using,  but i have found ten year old persistent messages on a queue. A delayed delivery message is just a message with a special header put to the staging queue.   As long as your infrastructure has longevity and is reliable,  MQ should not lose messages.   If you specifically wanted to limit it, you could put a CAPEXPRY on the queue,  this should limit the delayed delivery value.